# AJAX get query not causing page to load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

I am using the following code to detect a change in a form selection and then send an AJAX get request with the data.

```
    $("#configset").change(function(){

   $.ajax({  
            method: "get",
            url: "/bmcfg/index.php", // This is the url that will be requested

            data: {"configset": $("#configset").val(),
                   "configupdate": "update"
                  },
       success:function()//we got the response
       {
       // alert('Successfully called:'+ $("#configset").val());
       },
       error:function(){alert('Exeption:');}

            });

});
```

On the server side I am using PHP to process the request.

```
if ((isset($_GET['configupdate']) and $_GET['configupdate'] == 'update'))
{
    echo 'get received:'.$_GET['configupdate'];
    include project.html.php
```

}

I never see the echo line being printed on that new page ? I just want PHP to load the new webpage without having to sent it back to the ajax as data.

Comment: Where do you expect to see the echo line "printed?" It will be the response sent back from the server, so you should see that value in your `success` callback in JavaScript.

Comment: include 'project.html.php';    in that web page. Its included after the echo.

Comment: `success:function(response){alert(response);}` what it says? check

Comment: yes I get the entire webpage back in 'response'. How do I display the new webpage ?

Comment: yup. I just want PHP to receive the GET request and send the page to the browser instead of AJAX

Comment: I was using jQuery to detect the change. I already have a button. underneath the form whose change I am detecting. Is there a way I can send that button submit using JS or Jquery on detecting a change ?

Comment: Yes, you can submit when detecting a change. I would need to see the code in order to suggest how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to apparently not use AJAX but use a form and submit the form on detecting a change. AJAX will send and receive data within AJAX. So the data sent by the server side PHP script will be sent to AJAX as well.

This can be fixed by using form submission using JQuery.

```
$("#selectid").change(function(){  <------ this is the select tag "id"
    $("#formid").submit();     <---- this is the form tag "id"           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to the function that gets the value from PHP :

```
 success:function( data )//we got the response
       {
        alert( data );    // <========== VALUE ECHOED FROM PHP.
       }
```

Comment: I would just like the PHP script to run. Is there a way to make it do that ? Because the script will load some new variables and I will be suing them in a diff page that the script loads

Comment: @amansehgal0u2, you are using ajax to call PHP, when the PHP runs the result will come back to ajax. That's the way it works. By the way, the PHP is actually running, but you were not seeing the result.

Comment: Yes thanks. Issue in my understanding. I see the entire damn webpage now placed in data. But thats not what I wanted lol. I guess I want the PHP script to send that webpage down to the browser

Comment: I'm affraid the answer to your question is NO WAY. Ajax won't allow that.